# Drawing multiple views on android

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I have found similar questions but none of those give a proper answer to my question.

I have a class that is a view.

```
public class Actor extends View {
private ShapeDrawable drawable;

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = 100;
int height = 40;

public Actor(Context context) {
    super(context);

    drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    drawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
    drawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    drawable.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

What I want to do now is draw multiple instances of this view on the android screen. I can draw one by doing this in an activity:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Dimension actor1 = new Actor(this);
    setContentView(actor1);
}
```

My goal is to draw multiple instances of it, of course with other x and y parameters so they don't overlap. I don't want to convert the view to a bitmap first to get it in a canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - create some layout, and then call setContentView(yourlayout).

Then, use such method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
FrameLayout mainLayout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
Dimension actor1 = new Actor(this);
mainLayout.addView(actor1);
```

Comment: I tried to extend the ViewGroup class in such a way that I could do it the way you say, but I couldn't get this working.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get. Why so serious? Updated my answer.

Comment: I mean I didn't get a layout working on which I could do this. But I'm just thinking, mayby RelativeLayout will do the job, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Anyway, you can set only one content view to your activity.

Comment: The FrameLayout did the trick, I didn't have to bother about custom ViewGroups and stuff, ... thank you :) (mayby you can put setContentView(mainLayout); in your answer and delete the first line in case other people want to see it)

Comment: Actually it didn't do the trick... the views are all displayed in their own little "frame", so when I apply a drag and drop on them, the can only move in their own little frame and not outside of it. Making the frames larger doesn't work, since the frames begin to cover each other.

Comment: I used setTranslation method for View (actor1 in your case) to move them. Available from Honeycomb. In other versions I used margins (but maybe you can try to copy this method from Honeycomb, I didn't try this).